# MongoDB - 'conn' Mogo Object Remote Code Execution

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, mongoose

in security test for my application, return this error

`MongoDB - 'conn' Mogo Object Remote Code Execution`

I used mongoose and this is a piece of module

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('user' ,  mongoose.Schema({
    phone:{
        type:Number,
    },
    verifyCode:{
        type:Number,
    },
    name:{
        type:String,
    },
    refCode:{
        type:String,
    },
    slefRefCode:{
        type:String,
    },
    report:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    city:{
        type:String,
    },
    status:{
        type:String,
        default:'notVerify'
    },
    subSet:{
        type:Array
    },
    time:{
        type:Number
    }
}));

module.exports = User;
```

and

mongoose
.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/****?authSource=admin", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  user: "****",
  pass: "****",
})